# TViOS third party library marmelroy/Zip

Tags: ios, swift, shared-libraries, tvos9.1

Wanted to use carthage and this library...

https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

But having updated brew and downloaded the latest carthage & Zip code I get this error when I try to build?

Module file was created for incompatible target arm64-apple-ios8.0: /Users/localuser/blah/blah/blah/blah/Carthage/Build/iOS/Zip.framework/Modules/Zip.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule

My target is AppleTV iOS version 9.2: Noted too this error message ...

ld: building for tvOS, but linking against dylib built for iOS, file '/Users/localuser/blah/blah/blah/Carthage/Build/iOS/Zip.framework/Zip' for architecture arm64

Am I attempting the impossible here? Is there a way around it?

localuser$ carthage update --platform iOS
*** Cloning Zip**
 Checking out Zip at "0.3.4"
 **xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/rd/m94y05zs6836d9lrmh44f0b40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.O5thOi.log
*** Building scheme "Zip" in Zip.xcodeproj

And this ...

*** Checking out Zip at "0.3.4"**
 xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/rd/m94y05zs6836d9lrmh44f0b40000gp/T/carthage-xcodebuild.vhb9nL.log
 **Building scheme "Zip OSX" in Zip.xcodeproj
*** Building scheme "Zip" in Zip.xcodeproj

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the library Zip (https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) is 0.4.3 and it can be easily installed with the CocoaPods or the Carthage. I tested it on tvOS 9.2.